# read only certain columns

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsx

I would like to only read certain columns into a pandas dataframe from an excel file. I would like to specify this via the column ranges via `usecols` to specify this, but am faced with an error. What is the correct way to specify the column ranges as letters (yes, I know I could provide the column indicies, instead)?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx", usecols="A:AV", header=None)
```

> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py in
>   read_excel(io, sheetname, header, skiprows, skip_footer, index_col,
>   names, parse_cols, parse_dates, date_parser, na_values, thousands,
>   convert_float, has_index_names, converters, dtype, true_values,
>   false_values, engine, squeeze, **kwds)
>       207         skip_footer=skip_footer, converters=converters, dtype=dtype,
>       208         true_values=true_values, false_values=false_values, squeeze=squeeze,
>   --> 209         **kwds)
>       210
>       211
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py in
>   _parse_excel(self, sheetname, header, skiprows, names, skip_footer, index_col, has_index_names, parse_cols, parse_dates, date_parser,
>   na_values, thousands, convert_float, true_values, false_values,
>   verbose, dtype, squeeze, **kwds)
>       508                                     squeeze=squeeze,
>       509                                     dtype=dtype,
>   --> 510                                     **kwds)
>       511
>       512                 output[asheetname] = parser.read()
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in
>   TextParser(*args, **kwds)    1910     """    1911     kwds['engine'] =
>   'python'
>   -> 1912     return TextFileReader(*args, **kwds)    1913    1914
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in
>   **init**(self, f, engine, **kwds)
>       762             self.options['has_index_names'] = kwds['has_index_names']
>       763
>   --> 764         self._make_engine(self.engine)
>       765
>       766     def close(self):
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in
>   _make_engine(self, engine)
>       993                                  ' "c", "python", or' ' "python-fwf")'.format(
>       994                                      engine=engine))
>   --> 995             self._engine = klass(self.f, **self.options)
>       996
>       997     def _failover_to_python(self):
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in
>   **init**(self, f, **kwds)    1994         # infer column indices from self.usecols if is is specified.    1995         self._col_indices =
>   None
>   -> 1996         self.columns, self.num_original_columns = self._infer_columns()    1997    1998         # Now self.columns has
>   the set of columns that we will process.
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in
>   _infer_columns(self)    2387                 else:    2388                     columns = [lrange(ncols)]
>   -> 2389                 columns = self._handle_usecols(columns, columns[0])    2390             else:    2391                 if
>   self.usecols is None or len(names) >= num_original_columns:
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in
>   _handle_usecols(self, columns, usecols_key)    2422                 for col in self.usecols:    2423                     if
>   isinstance(col, string_types):
>   -> 2424                         col_indices.append(usecols_key.index(col))    2425
>   else:    2426                         col_indices.append(col)

```
In [20]: pd.__version__
Out[20]: '0.20.2'
```

file: [test.xlsx](https://nofile.io/f/QAn44EWgExc/test.xlsx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need upgrade to `pandas 0.21.0` ([dev discussion](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/16488)):

```
df = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx", usecols='A:B', header=None)                              
print (df.head())

          0                    1
0  sequence  2015-02-11 00:00:00
1        Aa                 6239
2    AaBpL5                  NaN
3    AaCjL5                  NaN
4    AaDrL2                  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

df=pd.read_excel("test.xlsx",usecols="A:AE")

The above command worked for me in IDLE with python version - 3.11.3 ,
pandas version - 2.0.2

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34541915)